# Space between an object and the ground truth bounding box

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, object-detection

Which way is better for drawing the ground truth boxes for object detection?

1. Drawing as tight as the sides of the box touch the border of the object, or

   [image: 1]
2. Make a little space between the box and the object?

   [image: 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first image is a better bounding box.  A perfect bounding box has no space in between the edges of the object and the box, but it also fully contains the object.